# C# - Passing Delegate as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, .net, exception, delegates

I am trying to get familiar with the concept of delegates in C#.  I have created this console application so far:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DelegatesTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArithmeticOperation.ArOpDel additionDelegate = new ArithmeticOperation.ArOpDel(ArithmeticOperation.Addition);
            Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate(10, 5)));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**ArithmeticOperation.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DelegatesTest
{
    public static class ArithmeticOperation
    {
        public delegate int ArOpDel(int x, int y);

        public static string ConvertResultToString(ArOpDel del)
        {
            string result = String.Format("The result of the {0} operation is {1}", del.Method.Name, del.ToString());
            return result;
        }

        public static int Addition(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Subtraction(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }

        public static int Multiplication(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }

        public static int Division(int x, int y)
        {
            return x / y;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, I am using a static class called **ArithmeticOperation.cs** to perform some arithmetic operations.  The **ConvertResultToString** method takes one of the arithmetic operations methods as a parameter in order to display the result elegantly as a string.

Unfortunately, my code does not compile.  It is giving me the following error:

```
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'DelegatesTest.ArithmeticOperation.ArOpDel'
```

The error is being given on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate(10, 5)));
```

Can you please help me solve this problem as I am not very experienced with delegates?  In fact, I have created this application to learn about delegates.

Comment: Delegates are pre-generics C#. They exist. For legacy reasons. If you want to learn how to do things like that in C#, look at the `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` classes.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank yo for your suggestion nvoigt.  I will make sure to take a look at these two classes.

Comment: @nvoigt it's never bad to want to understand why this worked that way.
In fact, there are some environments in which using generics is possibly a bad idea (like MonoTouch a while back)

Comment: @TimothyGroote Thank you Timothy.  I agree with your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`additionDelegate(10, 5)` is an invocation of `additionDelegate` which actually is an `Addition` function. So, the result is an integer.

In order to pass a delegate you should pass `additionDelegate` itself instead of `additionDelegate(10, 5)`. But, in this case, the result of the operation will not be available in `ConvertResultToString` unless you invoke it there.

```
public static string ConvertResultToString(ArOpDel del)
{
     string result = String.Format("The result of the {0} operation is {1}", del.Method.Name, del(10, 5).ToString());
     return result;
}
```

...

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.  So the best way is to pass the numbers to the ConvertResultToString as parameters right?

Comment: @JohnDoe in this particular case - yes.

Comment: @JohnDoe if you need an example where delegates are really useful take look at LINQ. Not the only case for them, but they really shine there.

Comment: Thank you so much MadSorcerer :)  Your answer helped me get to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `additionDelegate(10, 5)` will return `int` by doing arithmetic operation, it will not return `deleagate` that's the reason of compilation error.

Comment: Hmm...  Where should I pass the parameters (integers) to the arithmetic operation please?  Because once I removed the parameters, it is giving me the error that ArOpDel does not take 0 arguments.

Comment: The parameters aren't the problem.
What you're getting back at runtime is *not* the delegate, but the *result* of the delegate, which is just a single integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate(10, 5)));
```

You are not passing the delegate here. You are *calling* it, which results in an `int`.

This would pass the delegate:

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate));
```

You would need to actually call the delegate somewhere though.

Comment: Thank you.  The solution now compiles.  However, where can I pass the numbers for the arithmetic operation please?

Answer (score 1):

when you do this

```
 Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate(10, 5)));
```

you are forcing the compiler  to execute the method and return  the result to pass it as an argument which in this case it's an int while the `ConvertResultTostring` expect a delegate 
here  how you  can get it work without using generic

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArithmeticOperation.ArOpDel additionDelegate = ArithmeticOperation.Addition;

            Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate,5,6));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public static class ArithmeticOperation
    {
        public delegate int ArOpDel(int x, int y);

        public static string ConvertResultToString(ArOpDel del,int x, int y )
        {
            string result = String.Format("The result of the {0} operation is {1}", del.Method.Name, del(x,y).ToString());
            return result;
        }

        public static int Addition(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Subtraction(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }

        public static int Multiplication(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }

        public static int Division(int x, int y)
        {
            return x / y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Kamel.  That's the way I did it now and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

`additionDelegate(10, 5)` means invoke the delegate,the result is an int type which does not match the `ConvertResultToString` method stub.
you need change

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate(10, 5)))
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(ArithmeticOperation.ConvertResultToString(additionDelegate))
```

and change

```
string result = String.Format("The result of the {0} operation is {1}", del.Method.Name, del.ToString());
```

to

```
string result = String.Format("The result of the {0} operation is {1}", del.Method.Name, del(10,5).ToString());
```